# NSJSONSerialization returning different results with same XML file

Tags: sql, objective-c, json, xml

I am either having an issue with my XML that is being generated via SQL and using NSJSONSerialization in Objective-C

I have two XMLs

First XML:

```
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringPunchListCellModel84zsBx89 xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<KeyValueOfstringPunchListCellModel84zsBx89>
<Key>ORC0023</Key>
<Value xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LosaniHomesSchedulingWebAPI.Models">
<d3p1:baseOrSchedStartList>
<string>11-09-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>10-08-2015 4:00:00 PM</string>
<string>11-08-2015 4:00:00 PM</string>
<string>12-08-2015 4:00:00 PM</string>
<string>13-08-2015 4:00:00 PM</string>
<string>14-08-2015 4:00:00 PM</string>
<string>14-08-2015 4:00:00 PM</string>
<string>25-08-2015 4:00:00 PM</string>
<string>31-07-2015 4:00:00 PM</string>
<string>14-09-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>14-09-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>14-10-2015 5:00:00 PM</string>
<string>15-10-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>16-10-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>19-10-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>21-10-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>23-10-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>27-10-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>28-10-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>29-10-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>02-11-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>02-11-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>04-11-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>09-11-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>11-11-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>12-11-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>23-11-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>26-11-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>27-11-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>27-11-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>01-12-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>02-12-2015 5:00:00 PM</string>
<string>02-12-2015 5:00:00 PM</string>
<string>03-12-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>03-12-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>10-12-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>17-12-2015 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>15-02-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>15-02-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>16-02-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>23-02-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>01-03-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>02-03-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>03-03-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>08-03-2016 5:00:00 PM</string>
<string>09-03-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>21-03-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>24-03-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>31-03-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>07-04-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>14-04-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>19-04-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>20-05-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>25-05-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>31-05-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>01-06-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>09-06-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>10-06-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>13-06-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
<string>21-06-2016 8:00:00 AM</string>
</d3p1:baseOrSchedStartList>
<d3p1:sortOrder>0</d3p1:sortOrder>
</Value>
</KeyValueOfstringPunchListCellModel84zsBx89>
```

and this what it returns when I use NSJSONSerialization:

```
{"ORC0023":{"baseOrSchedStartList":["11-09-2015 8:00:00 AM","10-08-2015 4:00:00 PM","11-08-2015 4:00:00 PM","12-08-2015 4:00:00 PM","13-08-2015 4:00:00 PM","14-08-2015 4:00:00 PM","14-08-2015 4:00:00 PM","25-08-2015 4:00:00 PM","31-07-2015 4:00:00 PM","14-09-2015 8:00:00 AM","14-09-2015 8:00:00 AM","14-10-2015 5:00:00 PM","15-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","16-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","19-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","21-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","23-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","27-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","28-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","29-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","02-11-2015 8:00:00 AM","02-11-2015 8:00:00 AM","04-11-2015 8:00:00 AM","09-11-2015 8:00:00 AM","11-11-2015 8:00:00 AM","12-11-2015 8:00:00 AM","23-11-2015 8:00:00 AM","26-11-2015 8:00:00 AM","27-11-2015 8:00:00 AM","27-11-2015 8:00:00 AM","01-12-2015 8:00:00 AM","02-12-2015 5:00:00 PM","02-12-2015 5:00:00 PM","03-12-2015 8:00:00 AM","03-12-2015 8:00:00 AM","10-12-2015 8:00:00 AM","17-12-2015 8:00:00 AM","15-02-2016 8:00:00 AM","15-02-2016 8:00:00 AM","16-02-2016 8:00:00 AM","23-02-2016 8:00:00 AM","01-03-2016 8:00:00 AM","02-03-2016 8:00:00 AM","03-03-2016 8:00:00 AM","08-03-2016 5:00:00 PM","09-03-2016 8:00:00 AM","21-03-2016 8:00:00 AM","24-03-2016 8:00:00 AM","31-03-2016 8:00:00 AM","07-04-2016 8:00:00 AM","14-04-2016 8:00:00 AM","19-04-2016 8:00:00 AM","20-05-2016 8:00:00 AM","25-05-2016 8:00:00 AM","31-05-2016 8:00:00 AM","01-06-2016 8:00:00 AM","09-06-2016 8:00:00 AM","10-06-2016 8:00:00 AM","13-06-2016 8:00:00 AM","21-06-2016 8:00:00 AM"],"sortOrder":0},"ORC0045":{"baseOrSchedStartList":["24-01-2016 8:00:00 AM","28-01-2016 8:00:00 AM","29-01-2016 8:00:00 AM","30-01-2016 8:00:00 AM","31-01-2016 8:00:00 AM","31-01-2016 4:00:00 PM","24-04-2015 8:00:00 AM","07-05-2015 8:00:00 AM","11-05-2015 5:00:00 PM","01-06-2015 8:00:00 AM","12-05-2015 8:00:00 AM","23-06-2015 5:00:00 PM","23-06-2015 5:00:00 PM","24-06-2015 8:00:00 AM","25-06-2015 8:00:00 AM","27-06-2015 8:00:00 AM","25-06-2015 8:00:00 AM","30-06-2015 8:00:00 AM","03-07-2015 8:00:00 AM","17-06-2015 4:00:00 PM","08-07-2015 8:00:00 AM","21-06-2015 4:00:00 PM","11-07-2015 8:00:00 AM","21-07-2015 8:00:00 AM","23-07-2015 8:00:00 AM","24-07-2015 8:00:00 AM","03-08-2015 9:00:00 AM","08-08-2015 8:00:00 AM","07-08-2015 8:00:00 AM","01-09-2015 8:00:00 AM","08-09-2015 8:00:00 AM","12-09-2015 5:00:00 PM","05-08-2015 5:00:00 PM","14-09-2015 9:00:00 AM","14-09-2015 9:00:00 AM","23-09-2015 8:00:00 AM","02-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","06-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","06-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","09-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","16-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","21-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","22-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","23-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","24-10-2015 5:00:00 PM","26-10-2015 9:00:00 AM","29-10-2015 8:00:00 AM","02-11-2015 9:00:00 AM","04-11-2015 8:00:00 AM","06-11-2015 8:00:00 AM","09-11-2015 9:00:00 AM","12-11-2015 8:00:00 AM","27-05-2016 8:00:00 AM","31-05-2016 8:00:00 AM","04-06-2016 8:00:00 AM","06-06-2016 9:00:00 AM","13-06-2016 9:00:00 AM","14-06-2016 8:00:00 AM","15-06-2016 8:00:00 AM","23-06-2016 8:00:00 AM"],"sortOrder":1}}
```

This is the second XML:

```
<Root>
  <KeyValue>
    <Key>ORC0023</Key>
    <Value>
      <baseOrSchedStartList>
        <string>2015-09-11T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-08-10T16:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-08-11T16:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-08-12T16:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-08-13T16:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-08-14T16:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-08-14T16:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-08-25T16:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-07-31T16:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-09-14T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-09-14T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-10-14T17:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-10-15T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-10-16T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-10-19T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-10-21T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-10-23T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-10-27T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-10-28T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-10-29T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-11-02T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-11-02T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-11-04T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-11-09T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-11-11T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-11-12T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-11-23T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-11-26T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-11-27T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-11-27T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-12-01T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-12-02T17:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-12-02T17:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-12-03T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-12-03T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-12-10T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2015-12-17T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-02-15T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-02-15T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-02-16T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-02-23T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-03-01T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-03-02T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-03-03T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-03-08T17:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-03-09T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-03-21T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-03-24T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-03-31T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-04-07T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-04-14T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-04-19T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-05-20T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-05-25T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-05-31T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-06-01T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-06-09T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-06-10T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-06-13T08:00:00</string>
        <string>2016-06-21T08:00:00</string>
      </baseOrSchedStartList>
    </Value>
  </KeyValue>
</Root>
```

as you can see they are very similar (except the second one has a Root and the first one does not)

and this is what it returns when I use NSJSONSerialization:

```
{"Root":{"KeyValue":[{"Key":"ORC0023","Value":{"baseOrSchedStartList":{"string":["2015-09-11T08:00:00","2015-08-10T16:00:00","2015-08-11T16:00:00","2015-08-12T16:00:00","2015-08-13T16:00:00","2015-08-14T16:00:00","2015-08-14T16:00:00","2015-08-25T16:00:00","2015-07-31T16:00:00","2015-09-14T08:00:00","2015-09-14T08:00:00","2015-10-14T17:00:00","2015-10-15T08:00:00","2015-10-16T08:00:00","2015-10-19T08:00:00","2015-10-21T08:00:00","2015-10-23T08:00:00","2015-10-27T08:00:00","2015-10-28T08:00:00","2015-10-29T08:00:00","2015-11-02T08:00:00","2015-11-02T08:00:00","2015-11-04T08:00:00","2015-11-09T08:00:00","2015-11-11T08:00:00","2015-11-12T08:00:00","2015-11-23T08:00:00","2015-11-26T08:00:00","2015-11-27T08:00:00","2015-11-27T08:00:00","2015-12-01T08:00:00","2015-12-02T17:00:00","2015-12-02T17:00:00","2015-12-03T08:00:00","2015-12-03T08:00:00","2015-12-10T08:00:00","2015-12-17T08:00:00","2016-02-15T08:00:00","2016-02-15T08:00:00","2016-02-16T08:00:00","2016-02-23T08:00:00","2016-03-01T08:00:00","2016-03-02T08:00:00","2016-03-03T08:00:00","2016-03-08T17:00:00","2016-03-09T08:00:00","2016-03-21T08:00:00","2016-03-24T08:00:00","2016-03-31T08:00:00","2016-04-07T08:00:00","2016-04-14T08:00:00","2016-04-19T08:00:00","2016-05-20T08:00:00","2016-05-25T08:00:00","2016-05-31T08:00:00","2016-06-01T08:00:00","2016-06-09T08:00:00","2016-06-10T08:00:00","2016-06-13T08:00:00","2016-06-21T08:00:00"]}}},{"Key":"ORC0045","Value":{"baseOrSchedStartList":{"string":["2016-01-24T08:00:00","2016-01-28T08:00:00","2016-01-29T08:00:00","2016-01-30T08:00:00","2016-01-31T08:00:00","2016-01-31T16:00:00","2015-04-24T08:00:00","2015-05-07T08:00:00","2015-05-11T17:00:00","2015-06-01T08:00:00","2015-05-12T08:00:00","2015-06-23T17:00:00","2015-06-23T17:00:00","2015-06-24T08:00:00","2015-06-25T08:00:00","2015-06-27T08:00:00","2015-06-25T08:00:00","2015-06-30T08:00:00","2015-07-03T08:00:00","2015-06-17T16:00:00","2015-07-08T08:00:00","2015-06-21T16:00:00","2015-07-11T08:00:00","2015-07-21T08:00:00","2015-07-23T08:00:00","2015-07-24T08:00:00","2015-08-03T09:00:00","2015-08-08T08:00:00","2015-08-07T08:00:00","2015-09-01T08:00:00","2015-09-08T08:00:00","2015-09-12T17:00:00","2015-08-05T17:00:00","2015-09-14T09:00:00","2015-09-14T09:00:00","2015-09-23T08:00:00","2015-10-02T08:00:00","2015-10-06T08:00:00","2015-10-06T08:00:00","2015-10-09T08:00:00","2015-10-16T08:00:00","2015-10-21T08:00:00","2015-10-22T08:00:00","2015-10-23T08:00:00","2015-10-24T17:00:00","2015-10-26T09:00:00","2015-10-29T08:00:00","2015-11-02T09:00:00","2015-11-04T08:00:00","2015-11-06T08:00:00","2015-11-09T09:00:00","2015-11-12T08:00:00","2016-05-27T08:00:00","2016-05-31T08:00:00","2016-06-04T08:00:00","2016-06-06T09:00:00","2016-06-13T09:00:00","2016-06-14T08:00:00","2016-06-15T08:00:00","2016-06-23T08:00:00"]}}}]}}
```

as you can see this looks different then the first JSON. Why is it doing this and what would be best way to fix this? Here is my stored procedure. Basically what I am trying to is take the first XML and redo it in SQL (which I did and is the second XML) but its not serializing it properly. What am I doing wrong?

I can provide the SQL that is generating the XML if need be.

Here is the call I am making to get the JSON Data:

```
NSDictionary *punchList = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&myError]];
```

Comment: This is extremely unclear. What is the problem? Taking the XML and "redoing it in SQL"? (I don't even know what you mean by that.) Converting that to JSON? Recreating the XML? Recreating the JSON? You have to identify which step in the process is not generating the correct result and then focus on that, and isolate us from the rest of your process. And once you figure out which step is the problem, rather than dumping us with a lot of code, you have to see if you can distill this down to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Talking about JSON and XML in the same question leads me to believe you are very confused.  Figure out what you're doing, and come back with a specific question.